# How to create a simple reflection using imagemagick with dynamic image sizing?

Tags: image

I've trying to use imagemagick to create a simple reflection, however the documentation has fixed sizes. I've tried to read in the height and width and use those variables but this doesn't produce a reflection.

Here's the documentation
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/advanced/

Here's the sample code

```
  convert pokemon.gif \( +clone -flip \) -append \
          -size 100x100 xc:black +swap \
          -gravity North -geometry +0+5 -composite  reflect_perfect.png
```

Here's my bash script, with my widths and heights...

```
#!/bin/bash

infile="framed.png"

ww=`convert $infile -format "%w" info:`
hh=`convert $infile -format "%h" info:`

convert $infile -alpha on \
  \( +clone -flip -channel A -evaluate multiply .35 +channel \) -append \
  -size ${ww}x${hh} xc:black +swap \
  -gravity North -geometry +0+5 -composite  reflect_alpha.png
```

My resulting image is exactly the same as the source image.

Here's the exact image I'm using
https://www.dropbox.com/s/l8gtieuqi1yoipm/iPhoneXR-4-categories_framed.png?dl=0

Comment: Thanks @fmw42 I'm using mac / mojave i've added this to my bash file `sh 3Dreflection.sh -r 20 -s off $infile output.png` but I'm getting the follow errors. ```3Dreflection.sh: line 135: type: 3Dreflection.sh: not found. 3Dreflection.sh: line 364: 3Drotate: command not found```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size for the black background must be larger than twice the height of the input and at least as wide as the input. So I would do the following in Imagemagick

Input:

[image]

```
infile="zelda1.jpg"
ww=`convert $infile -format "%[fx:1.5*w]" info:`
hh=`convert $infile -format "%[fx:2.1*h]" info:`
convert $infile -alpha on \
\( +clone -flip -channel A -evaluate multiply .35 +channel \) -append \
-size ${ww}x${hh} xc:black +swap \
-gravity North -geometry +0+5 -composite  reflect_alpha.png
```

[image]

But you can try my bash unix Imagemagick shell script, 3Dreflection at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.html, if you want more flexibility.

ADDITION:

To answer your question, it does not matter if PNG or JPG. The issue is that you have transparency. If you put a transparent background, then

```
infile="WPB-wtpC.png"
ww=`convert $infile -format "%[fx:1.5*w]" info:`
hh=`convert $infile -format "%[fx:2.1*h]" info:`
convert $infile \
\( +clone -flip -alpha on -channel A -evaluate multiply .35 +channel +write tmp1.png \) -append +write tmp2.png \
-size ${ww}x${hh} xc:none +swap \
-gravity North -geometry +0+5 -compose over -composite  reflect_alpha.png
```

[image]

If you use a black background, then

```
infile="WPB-wtpC.png"
ww=`convert $infile -format "%[fx:1.5*w]" info:`
hh=`convert $infile -format "%[fx:2.1*h]" info:`
convert $infile \
\( +clone -flip -alpha on -channel A -evaluate multiply .35 +channel +write tmp1.png \) -append +write tmp2.png \
-size ${ww}x${hh} xc:black +swap \
-gravity North -geometry +0+5 -compose over -composite  reflect_alpha.png
```

[image]

NOTE: I had a typo in the first zelda image code. I accidentally typed w rather than h in the hh equation, which I have now fixed. That may have messed you up.

Comment: Thanks, it's very odd, I've just getting the same image back with that code also. :(

Comment: `convert -version`
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.8-27 Q16 x86_64 2019-02-12 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms ltdl lzma openexr png tiff webp xml zlib

Comment: @Jules Imagemagick V7 uses magick instead of convert. Convert will still work if you have installed legacy files but is using a V6 version not a V7 one. It is always best to add your exact version to your post as fmw42's code can probably be condensed for V7

Comment: Still get exactly the same output image as the source image 

Comment: I've added the image I'm using to my question, I wonder if it's the size or that it's a png file?

Comment: See my additional comments in my post to solve your issue